# allow all users to execute a bash script as root

Tags: bash, root

i want that my all users can run a bash script. But this bash script need to have root right, i want that this script is in read only and run with root right

my bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/swapoff -a
```

in my search i found solution but it not work, this is solution :

```
# chown root:root monshell.sh
# chmod 4755 monshell.sh
# exit
$ ./monshell.sh
```

but i have this error when i run with basic user :
swapoff: Not superuser.

Answer (score 6):

Creating a su root bash script is dangerous. A bash script is too easy to manipulate in ways you don't expect to run other commands. Every new su root executable is a new security risk.

The preferred way to grant rights like this is with sudo. Create a file /etc/sudoers.d/swapoff, as follows:

```
ALL ALL = /bin/swapoff -a
```

Then all users (the first ALL) on all hosts (2nd ALL) may run `sudo /bin/swapoff -a`. And each time they do that, it will be logged to syslog.